# What is the next version of SharePoint [After 2016]?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

SharePoint 2016 has been out for a  few months. I had a client ask when to expect the next version of SharePoint.  I sheepishly said, "Only Microsoft knows, and perhaps they do not yet know when for sure."  What information is currently available about releasing future SharePoint developments?

Comment: I think Microsoft don't know too. Maybe SP2016 is the last version. It is very obviously Microsoft is pushing everything to their cloud service.

Comment: If we all embrace the Cloud model we should stop thinking in versions. SharePoint Online is updated every 2 weeks

Answer (score 2):

It is just guess work. If we follow the pattern with the version numbers then I think next version will be 2019.
Like moss 2007 release around 2007, sp 2010 aging around 2010 so on

As we all know, MSFT strategy and preference is cloud.So cloud 1st approach may delay the next version or change the model for upcoming on prem version.

But one thing I can say, 2016 will not be last on-Prem version. As a lot of companies still not ready to move to cloud.

Comment: 2016 is probably the last version of Sharepoint on Premise. They are now laying more emphasis on the cloud as cloud services bring them more business and more profit.

Comment: Good guess! 2019 it is!

Comment: @Muskan. 2016 is not the last version of Sharepoint on Premise. Here Bill Bear from MS says that they don't have a plan to make SP 2016 the last on premise version:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2017/05/16/sharepoint-server-2016-and-beyond/